# getIntent().getStringExtra() returns null

Tags: android

I have `onClick` method in `MainActivity` as following,

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("I", "0");
    startActivity(i);
}
```

In `SecondActivity` I validated the `Intent` as following

```
if (getIntent().getStringExtra("I") == null) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "NOT NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

and started the `ThirdActivity` from `SecondActivity` as following

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Now when come back to `SecondActivity` from `ThirdActivity` `getIntent().getStringExtra("I")` returns `null`. I also tried overriding `onOptionsItemSelected` as following.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent i = getIntent();
            i.putExtra("I", "0");
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Now don't know how to fix this issue. I don't want to use `SharedPreference` for this issue.

Comment: You have to pass i.putExtra("I", "0"); again while coming from ThirdActivity to SecondActivity

Comment: @R.R.M I have added in `onOptionsItemSelected`. May be the way I added is wrong. Is it?

Comment: No I have given an answer. Please refer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not finishing any activity, and you are passing value from main activity to second, then calling third activity, just returning from the third activity and resuming the second activity, you are not passing any data to second activity while coming from third activity.

just change your code as follow:-

```
//from second to third
public void onClick(View view) {
Intent i = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
}

// returning from third to second
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, second.class);
i.putextra("I","0");
startActivity(i);
finish();
        break;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

also you can change like this:-

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("I","0");
startActivity(i);
finish();   

}

 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        onBackPressed();
        break;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

in your third activity only

if you dont want to startactivty then startActivtyForResult() from second to third:-

```
startActivityForResult(i,101);
```

implement onActivtyResult method in second activity:-

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     // Check which request we're responding to
if (requestCode == 101 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
// Now use data.getStringExtra("I");
}
}
```

for third activity just finish it in onBackpress() like:-

```
   @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 Intent resultData = new Intent();
 resultData.putExtra("I", "0");
 setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultData);
 finish();
 }

 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        onBackPressed();
        break;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: So, May I know how to pass?

Answer (score 2):

Please follow these steps:

1. start ThirdActivity for result

   ```
   public void onClick(View view) {
     Intent i = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
     startActivityForResult(i, 1);
   }
   ```
2. Update following method, add `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);`

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
     case android.R.id.home:
       Intent i = getIntent();
       i.putExtra("I", "0");
       setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
       break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
   ```
3. In SecondActivity, implement onActivityResult

   ```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       // Check which request we're responding to
       if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       // Now use data.getStringExtra("I");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Good solution friend. Added +1. But I am used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441750/getintent-getstringextra-returns-null/46441808#46441808. because it looks more simpler then this. Thank you.

Comment: Good but you are restarting the activity which is already being showing.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you come back from third activity to second activity, getIntent() returns the Intent of third activity and not the first.

And while navigating from third activity to second, you are not passing any string extra and hence you get a null value.

Comment: So, May I know how to pass?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `startActivityForResult()` method for your linking from `SecondActivity` to `ThirdActivity` this way, you can then use `setResult(intent)` before killing the `ThirdActivty`. Thus when you come back to your `SecondActivity` you will have the result intent you passed in your `ThirdActivty` inside the `onActivityResult` method of your `SecondActivity`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make a change when you move towards SecondActivity from ThirdActivity.:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SeconActivity.class);
i.putExtra("I",getIntent().getStringExtra("I"));
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass again

```
i.putExtra("I", "0");
```

from third activity to second activity

Answer (score 0):

try this :
put this on your thirdactivity

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("I","0");
    startActivity(i);
    finish();   

}
```

Comment: I don't want to `startActivity` again, I just want to use an activity that is already in backstack.